# Fill GridPane cell

Tags: javafx, gridpane

First of all I am a beginner in Java. I'm trying to create a Monopoly game in Java with JavaFX. I drew the board in a Gridpane.

```
public class BordView extends GridPane {


public BordView() {
    RowConstraints rowsEdge = new RowConstraints();
    rowsEdge.setPercentHeight(14);
    RowConstraints rowsMid = new RowConstraints();
    rowsMid.setPercentHeight(8);

    ColumnConstraints colEdge = new ColumnConstraints();
    colEdge.setPercentWidth(14);

    ColumnConstraints colMid = new ColumnConstraints();
    colMid.setPercentWidth(8);

    this.getColumnConstraints().addAll(colEdge, colMid,
            colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colEdge);
    this.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowsEdge, rowsMid,
            rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsEdge);

    this.setGridLinesVisible(true);
}
```

Now my question: How can I put a name, money value and color to those cells? Is there a way to get the coordinates or something of the cells. If so I can fill them with a loop.

Thanks in Advance,
Nathan

Comment: Just use [`add(Node node, int columnIndex, int rowIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-). See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY118)

Comment: Also there are the `addColumn` and `addRow` methods for adding more than one `Node` at a time.